# How to add Disqus to a React-Native project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, disqus

I have tried using `react-native-disqus` package which is available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-disqus

It gave me a lot of errors

If anyone knows how implement Disqus in React Native please help!
Thanks in advance!